# SSIS package - Filter the incoming data

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

A SQL Server stored procedure feeds my SSIS package ~90 Million rows of data.
Then inside my package, I need to divide the data in 3 pieces (based on year) and do further process.

Can you please guide me how divide (filter) the entire data by specifying year?
I don't want to store the whole data in some physical table.

Thanks

Comment: Usual method is to [use a Conditional Split](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-conditional-split/).  It's one of the available Data Flow Transformations inside your Data Flow Task.

Comment: Thanks Bacon Bits. I'll give it a shot, it sure looks promising.

Comment: I tried and it's perfectly working fine. Thanks again!